# Button position like game controller css, responsive

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design, responsive

I would like to put these 4 buttons in a way similar to a game controller.
The result that I obtain is the following. They should be on the center-bottom part of the screen, smaller and the have to be responsive. What I have to change? Should I use `#controls { position:relative;}`?

[image: Controls]

HTML Code:

```
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>...</head>

<body><div id="controls">
    <button id="keyboard_key_up" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_up.png"/></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_left" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_left.png" /></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_down" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_down.png" /></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_right" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_right.png" /></button>

</div>...</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
#keyboard_key_up {
    position: absolute;
    right:300px;
    bottom: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background: white;z

}

#keyboard_key_left {
    position: absolute;
    right:575px;
    bottom: 250px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;

}

#keyboard_key_down {
    position: absolute;
    right:300px;
    bottom: 250px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;

}

#keyboard_key_right {
    position: absolute;
    right:25px;
    bottom: 250px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for flex and grid should be pretty good this days, but depending on your target this might not work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

#controls {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
  align-self: end;
}

.movements_control {
  border: solid 1px black;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.movements_control img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

#keyboard_key_up {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

#keyboard_key_left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

#keyboard_key_down {}

#keyboard_key_right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

@media (min-width: 721px) {
  .movements_control {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .movements_control {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="keyboard_key_up" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_up.png"></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_left" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_left.png"></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_down" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_down.png"></button>
    <button id="keyboard_key_right" class="movements_control"><img src="public/img/keyboard_key_right.png"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank's! How can I now reduce the dimension of the buttons?

Comment: @Camilla8 you mean dinamically? you could use maybe calc() or media queries

Comment: Yes, now they are too big, but maybe using another device they could be ok

Comment: I wrote this button img {
    height: 10vh;
    } 
The dimensions are now fine using my browser, but for mobile it is not responsive and I can't see the arrows

Comment: @Camilla8 yeah, that might work. I updated the answer with a example media query.

Comment: The result with only your media queries is unlikely terrible http://it.tinypic.com/r/iep3b7/9

Comment: @Camilla8 I can't really test for that platforms but could you elaborate? what are you seeing ? What browser / OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
#controls {
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if this does not work, could you please send your code using plunker or codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaQPoW I can't upload my images, but that is the code

Comment: I removed all positions absolute from your  images id's and changed the #controls to `position: absolute`. I left a codepen for you:  [your code changed here](https://codepen.io/mbarem/pen/pOQpvR)

Comment: this is the result, unlikely it is not what I want http://it.tinypic.com/r/34hc47o/9

Comment: I changed the css in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/mbarem/pen/pOQpvR), i think is what you need, let me know :) (if you changed the order of the images you get what you need)

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think that this is working: http://it.tinypic.com/r/21jq1s2/9